# How to query a table on timestamp with Sequelize ORM

Tags: node.js, api, sequelize.js

I would like to query my Table for the value at midnight (00:00:00) everyday.
So The system gets a value every minutes but I want the value at 00:00:00 so I can plot daily sales.

Here is how my code looking so far:

```
  const data = await Chart.findAll({
    where: {
      DATEPART(hour, TimeStamp): 0,
      DATEPART(minute, TimeStamp): 0
    },
  });
  res.send(data);
};
```

TimeStamp is the name of the field on SQL table that contain the time stamp.

Comment: You have taged MYSQL, but "DATEPART" is no MYSQL function, but is used in SqlServer DB's. Could you please review this and tell us if your where clause is wrong or your DBMS?

Comment: I've reviewed the question.In general terms I would like to query for a specific time, is that even possible ?

Comment: Please show the model definition